# how to get the desired value in bash shell from the lshw output?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

I want to extract the info from `lshw` output where it says:

```
-cpu
    product: ......
```

I want only the product info of this `-cpu`.

How can I do that with `awk` or `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter using the utility `lshw`, itself:

```
lshw -C cpu
```

That prints only the cpu part. But if you **only** want the product part then you need awk:

```
lshw -C cpu | awk '$1=="product:"{$1=""; print}'
```

It searches for the string `product:` in the first field variable and removes that part before printing the rest of the line.

Answer (score -2):

Mr Moderator please move this as a comment to chaos’ answer, I can’t comment because I don’t have the beans ;-)
I do believe such commands like lshw or lsblk should have a way to return the exact desired string without parsing the output with awk or sed or whatever, especially now that these tools are often localized and you must parse differently according to language! I have been struggling like mad with this issue.

Comment: The easy way to un-localize a command for parsing by scripts/tools is (in Bash or Bourne/POSIX-y shells) `LANG=C shw -C cpu`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/562257)

Comment: Anyway my request remains 100% valid because the retrieval of raw values would be less time consuming and error-prone, at least for non sed/awk experts, than having to fiddle with parsing tools.

Comment: Inflexible enforcement of arbitrary rules : you moderators won’t complain when you are replaced by bots. BTW the awk/sed stuff may become obsolete with new releases of the tool.